# Compute SLA between dates including weekends

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help on an Excel formula that will compute the SLA between 2 dates. NETWORKDAYS() doesn't include weekends and I need something that will include Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is SLA (I searched, but it was ambiguous)?

Comment: @slhck Yeah, that was my likeliest candidate, but I'm trying to figure out if all the OP needs is just the number of days between two dates...

Comment: @slhck Thanks for bringing that one to my attention, though.

Comment: Possibly Service Level Agreement e.g. in business scenarios there is often an SLA that correspondence will be replied to within a certain number of days

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for the number of days between two dates, just subtract them:

```
      A         B      C
1  11/4/10   =NOW()  =b1-a1
```

If there's a time involved (like when calling `=NOW()`) you will end up with a fractional component, but just round as required by your industry's rules.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this but I used the DATEDIF() since I also need to calculate the time and not just the number of days.